# Intershop 7 - Problem adding a new index into database

Tags: intershop

I am trying to run a DatabaseIndexesPreparer through DBMigrate.bat and everytime it fails, therefore I have tried running needed SQL directly through Oracle SQLDeveloper and it also fails there with the same message.
This is the snippet I am trying to run:
`EXEC staging_ddl.create_index('HWDB_ID_INDEX', 'PRODUCT', 'HWDBID', 'IS_INDX', 'NONUNIQUE', 0);`

This is the result/message I receive:

```
ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "INTERSHOP.SQL_UTIL", line 149
ORA-06512: at "INTERSHOP.SQL_UTIL", line 49
ORA-06512: at "INTERSHOP.DDL", line 354
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "INTERSHOP.STAGING_DDL", line 235
ORA-06512: at line 1
00906. 00000 -  "missing left parenthesis"
```

### Additional info

All of this is done on Intershop 7.10.
`HWDBID` is a direct custom attribute (DCA) added successfully through DBMigrate following this cookbook:
https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/L24707

The SQL snippet is also based on section 4 which deals with adding database index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXEC staging_ddl.create_index('HWDB_ID_INDEX', 'PRODUCT', '(HWDBID)', 'IS_INDX', 'NONUNIQUE', 0);
```

It seems like you always need to wrap the columns in parenthesis. From the example i found in 7.9 and 7.10 it is done like this.